# Werewolves in Tolkien: Why is this name used?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, werewolf

The werewolves in Tolkien’s stories lack the main characteristic of modern and historical depictions of werewolves elsewhere, namely, the ability (willing or otherwise) to change their form between man and wolf.

They are instead consistently described as large WOLVES, with the closest werewolf-like thing about them being their (always malevolent) intelligence, the ability to speak, and possession of/by evil/fell spirits.

Is there any reason that Tolkien chose to name these beasts werewolves, or rather, anything that differentiates them from the many other (intelligent) wolves and/or wargs already described?

Comment: You should provide a quote and a reference for this.

Comment: Because they are "aware-wolves"

Comment: Where are the werewolves in Tolkien?

Comment: @ToddWilcox In the Silmarillion.  Seem to be extinct by the end of the First Age.  It also has vampires that don’t fit the traditional image.

Comment: @Suchiuomizu  No, in The Fellowship of the Rings" Gandalf tells Frodo that the servants of Sauron include wargs and werewolves and vampires.  And later they are attacked by what seem like werewolves soon before entering Moria.

Comment: I tought that was wargs.

Comment: @Oni Same thing. I guess Tolkien foresaw OP's conundrum and changed the name.

Comment: Given Tolkien’s linguistic backround (even forming the entire basis for the stories) and the origins of the word ‘werewolf’ this question could be cleaned up and answered quite neatly by someone smarter than myself. I’ve never tried an edit, but here goes nothing..

Comment: @M.A.Golding - where in the Fellowship does Gandalf say the word 'vampire'? Not even Peter Jackson went that far. The term 'vampire-like' is in the Hobbit

Answer (score 14):

I very much doubt that Tolkien cared greatly about modern ideas of werewolves and especially gaming, comic-book and movie notions of what werewolves are.  (If for no other reason than that they hadn't been invented yet!)

Older traditions about the supernatural are *much* less precise and consistent than modern. The ancient traditions were rarely codified and rarely self-consistant. E.g., the modern notions of the Norse gods are a modern systematizing of stories which themselves were mostly codified and written down by Icelandic Christian scholars who tried to make sense of stories several centuries after they were actually living stories. (And even in a single work such as the Prose Edda, there are still pretty basic contradictions between the stories.)  Further, what other fragmentary information we have about the sources shows huge regional and temporal variations in things as basic as the powers and personalities of gods like Odin and Thor.

Werewolves in history are also not so simple as modern tidying would lead you to believe.  (For example wolf-riders in some areas seem to have been called werewolves.)  Tolkien was a scholar of and was steeped in the older stories.  He would have cared little if *his* werewolves owed nothing to, say, Lon Chaney.

Let's look at his usage, where we see "wargs," "werewolves," and "wolves".

There were no wargs named as such in *Silmarillion*, and the werewolves seem to be quasi-demonic wolves.  I say "quasi-demonic" because they are described as wolves with a rather nasty affect:

> From time to time they saw two eyes kindled in the dark, and a werewolf devoured one of the companions;

Tolkien seems to make no real distinction between a wolf and a werewolf:

> But when the wolf came for Beren, Felagund put forth all his power, and burst his bonds; and he wrestled with the werewolf, and slew it with his hands and teeth;

In fact, they are said to be wolves possessed by evil spirits:

> Sauron brought werewolves, fell beasts inhabited by dreadful spirits that he had imprisoned in their bodies.

The only instances of *shapeshifting* involving werewolves are when Sauron and Beren turn themselves into werewolves, Beren using a shape-shifting skin, the "Hame of Draugluin", Draugluin being

> a dread beast, old in evil lord and sire of the werewolves of Angband

In *LotR*, wargs and werewolves are listed among the servants of Sauron. (This is the only mention of werewolves.) This can be taken as evidence that they are different, but Tolkien also lists orcs and goblins (which aren't different in kind) in the same way.

Based on their behavior, wargs appear to be unusually intelligent wolves, but not necessarily of human intelligence.

Bottom line:

(a) These creatures (whatever they are) play a very, very minor role in the stories and it's not clear that Tolkien really thought deeply about them.

(b) This was written before the modern zest for systematizing magic: the uncanny and the supernatural was dominant.

(c) Tolkien was well aware of the vagaries of myth and legend and probably wasn't greatly troubled by it -- at least when it wasn't part of his own legendarium.

Comment: your point about werewolves being largely the product in much of the public's mind of the 1940 universal/curt siodmak flick is a good. i would say that the "man" part of werewolf then refers to their minds being the same level of a human's in Tolkien.

Answer (score 9):

The Oxford English Dictionary provides an obsolete definition of *werewolf* as

> also, an exceptionally large and ferocious wolf.

It is almost certainly this definition that Tolkien had in mind, despite any more modern meaning of the word.

The OED also casts doubt on the analysis of *werewulf* as being a compound of Old English *wer* ("man") and *wulf* ("wolf"), due (for example) to variants of the word starting with *war-* and *var-* instead.

Comment: It's worth noting that Tolkien worked on 'W' in the OED in the 20s, so 'werewolf' may have passed through while he was there. Though he may not have been there long enough; I know he worked on 'walrus' and 'wallop'.

Comment: Actually, I just checked (https://public.oed.com/blog/jrr-tolkien-and-the-oed/) and it seems he may have only worked on the fasicle 'W to Wash', so in all likelihood no 'werewolf'. But http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Oxford_English_Dictionary notes some later words, including 'wold'.

Comment: I forgot he spent some time on the OED! In general, though, he used lots of archaic words. *The Book of Lost Tales*, for instance, includes lots of uses of *an* in its meaning of *if*. His usage of such was toned down a bit in his later published writings.